# How to fit different components into mat-sidenav-content?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to build an Angular web app that features an `Angular Material Sidenav` on top of each page. I want to have the sidenav appear above each component, but the tag `<mat-sidenav-content>` takes up the entire screen, pushing the components out of view.
The solution for a single component would be to do something like this:

```html
<mat-sidenav-content>
  <app-example></app-example>
</mat-sidenav-content>
```

However, I need to use this for multiple components on different pages and I would like to avoid copying the sidenav code for each particular component.

Comment: Make the sidenav its own component and re-use it in your other pages.

Comment: If I needed to use the sidenav component for two different pages, how would I change the name of the components inside of <mat-sidenav-content> of the sidenav?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to be done similar to what you did, but instead of 'manually load' the desired component, you have to use the **Angular Router** and its **Routes** to do it, using **"< router-outlet></ router-outlet >"** instead of the component names, like this:

```
<mat-sidenav-content>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</mat-sidenav-content>
```

As I see you a little bit lost about it, I leave you [HERE](https://indepth.dev/posts/1235/how-to-reuse-common-layouts-in-angular-using-router-2) a documentation with **further and detailed explanation**, [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-qcfwty?file=src/app/layout/main-layout/main-layout.component.html) an **stackblitz example** with a forked classic layout example, where you can see how it goes and where you can tinker at will.